# Modify a standard class for one application only

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is there any way in Python to modify a standard class in such a way that 1) the modified class is only seen by one specific application, 2) all instances created within that application use the modified class, and 3) when I upgrade Python, my modifications will not get lost?

The standard approach would involve creating a child of the class in question. This would satisfy requirement #1 and #3, but not #2, and that doesn't help me at all (unfortunately, I do not control the creation of the class's instances, I would have to rewrite a lot of other people's code).

I imagine I could modify the actual class source in Python/lib/..., but that would only satisfy requirement #2, not #1 and #3. Also, it would only work for me - if I wanted to give the final application to someone else, they would also have to modify their library code, which can't really be expected.

Unfortunately, I am not familiar enough with Python to know any other solutions. I know that with Delphi, I could either use a method hook, possibly in combination with a class helper, or simply copy the library file involved to my application's directory and modifying it there - that file would take precedence over the system library. Can I do something like that in Python, preferably both in version 2 and 3?

(Specifically, I need to modify the standard HTTPConnection and the Urllib's HTTPConnectionPool.)

Answer (score 0):

Apparently I have to answer my own questions. The solution is actually quite simple in Python:

____httphook.py____

```
import http.client

def replacement_getresponse(self):
    print("Reading response from my code")
    return self.original_getresponse()

def install_hook():
    http.client.HTTPConnection.original_getresponse = http.client.HTTPConnection.getresponse
    http.client.HTTPConnection.getresponse = replacement_getresponse
```

____test.py____

```
import http.client
import httphook
httphook.install_hook()
# Now my replacement function gets called
```